# Via SSIS, cannot connect to mysql DB with User DSN that connects successfully and is in ODBC.INI registry

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, datasource, dsn

Through an `SSIS` package, I need to export data from a `mySql` database. So I created a User Data Source with both versions of the `mysql odbc 5.3 driver` (ANSI & Unicode), and both connect successfully through the `ODBC Data Source Administrator`.

So in VS2008 (SSIS), I select `Odbc Data Provider` and then select the mysql user DSN that I created and tested. Once selected, when I click "Test Connection", I get error: *Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.* I get the same error with both user DSNs.

What can the problem be? We have `Windows Server Enterprise SP2` and I don't have administrator access, which is why I can't create a System DSN.

I checked in the Registry Editor and both datasources are under `ODBC.INI` and they're configured correctly. I also read to change from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` but I still get the same error.

Finally, I created a `File DSN` which also connects successfully, but I'm not sure how to configure SSIS to look at that data source.

I also installed `MySql Connector/ODBC 5.1.13` thinking it could be the driver, but I receive the same error.

I also noticed that when I create a data source from the ODBC data source administrator, I can see all mysql drivers, plus the older version that I installed today. On the other hand, when I create a "machine data source" from the VS2008 (SSIS) interface, I don't see any of the mysql drivers. In other words, I cannot create a mysql data source from within VS2008.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those drivers are likely 32bit only. In your SSIS Project, there is a setting that controls whether it's 64 (default) or 32 bit.

Comment: I had previously changed `Run64BitRuntime` to False, thinking that could be the issue. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I downloaded the x86 64-bit drivers since I was running VS2008 in a 64-bit OS. With this install I could create a DSN from the ODBC data source administrator but not from VS2008.

So I installed the x86 32-bit driver, and everything is working fine. On a side-note, I can't create a DSN through a 64-bit OS using this x86 32-bit driver. But I can create a "machine data source" from within VS2008.